# Jquery for click function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, gallery

I want to be able to click on a thumb and show the larger picture on the gallery.  Here is my view.

## view

```
<div class="gallery">

 <ul class="slideshow">
  <% @images.each do |img|%>
   <li>
      <%= link_to image_tag(...), :alt => img.name ), img %>
   </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<div class="thumbs">
 <% @images.each do |img|%>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="<%= img.images... %>" class="slideshow">
   <%= image_tag(...)%>
 </a>
<% end %>
</div>

</div>
```

here is my js code

## js

```
function click() {

$('.thumbs').click(
function() {
var gallery = $(this).attr("rel");
$('ul.slideshow').removeClass('show');
$(this).addClass('show');
$('slideshow').html('<img src="' + gallery + '" />');
return false;
})
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  Right now, the larger slideshow also has a setInterval so all the different larger images rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Why r u using this inside the click() function.. You can directly use like this..

```
$('.thumbs').click(function() {
var gallery = $(this).attr("rel");
$('ul.slideshow').removeClass('show');
$(this).addClass('show');
$('slideshow').html('<img src="' + gallery + '" />');
return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi.  I just added a function called click.  What you had was code I started with, but it didn't work.